# How do I jump with the Boots of Introspection?

Tags: candy-box-2

How do I jump while using the Boots of Introspection? It is really starting to annoy me and I've tried using every key on my keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You press the Jump button (or hit <kbd>J</kbd>). You will move forward while in the air.

[image]

Note that in order to jump you need the pogo stick, which you get by

> clicking the `*` in the mountains.